# Unable to print the background text like watermark in all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

[How can I add a large faded text background via css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986216/how-can-i-add-a-large-faded-text-background-via-css/15986317#15986317)

please refer the above link. watermark is working with the solution provided. But i am printing the html page using window.print(). Only the first page is printed with background text. How can i repeat the text as background for all other pages which is printed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use @media rule in your CSS allows you to target different media types, and screen sizes, from a single stylesheet.
You can decide layout of printable page and accordingly hide and show elements from the page

```
  @media print {#header, #footer, #Toolbar{ display: none !important;} 
   }
```

[This link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) might help you writing styles for printing.

Comment: thanks for your reply !! i am using the background text only for my tbody. how is that possible..

Comment: if i use the background text for thead and tfoot and use the below code its working fine                    thead {
  display:table-header-group;
 }

 tfoot {
  display:table-footer-group;  
 }      but for tbody how can i print for all pages.